# How to find a specific instance of a class through a class variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Class():
    id_list = []

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        Class.id_list.append(self.id)

class1 = Class("Bob", 0)
class2 = Class("John", 1)
```

What I want to do is go through the ID of each instance of Class, and if it matches a certain ID then it tells me the name of the class, is that possible?
For example: If I'm looking for "John" I look for the ID number 1

Comment: Why not just store tuples of `(id, class_name)`?

Comment: If the name is the key, the thing you want to reference it by, then you should use a dict()

Comment: I use the class for more than just that, I wanted to know if it was possible to just use the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only store the `id` value of each instance in the `id_list` class variable, there's no easy way to get at the corresponding name. However, if you could change your logic to store a reference to the whole instance in the list instead of the `id`, then you'd be able to look up any attribute you want on it. If doing lookups by `id` is common, you'd probably want to use a dictionary instead of a list to get faster lookups (though if the `id` values always start at `0` and increase by `1` each time, you'd be able to index the list in `O(1)` time too).

Try something like this:

```
class Class:
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, name): # no id arg needed
        self.name = name  # your code probably shouldn't have quotation marks around "name"
        self.id = len(self.instances) # automatically use the next available id value
        self.instances.append(self) # append a reference to the whole instance to the list

    @classmethod
    def lookup_class_name_by_id(cls, id):
        if 0 <= id < len(cls.instances):
            return cls.instances[id].name
        raise ValueError("Invalid ID {}".format(id))
```

Comment: That's an example of a perfect answer, nice one! :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you want to create a search by id function so that the id will link to a instance, you can create a dictionary for that, the key as the id and the value as the instance.

```
class Class():
    id_list = {} # id_list will be a dict instead

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name # no quotation marks...
        self.id = id
        Class.id_list[self.id] = self # save the id as key and self as he value

    @classmethod
    def search_by_id(cls, id):
        try:
            return cls.id_list[id] # return the instance with the id 
        except KeyError: # error check for if id does not exist
            raise KeyError("No user with id %s" % str(id))

class1 = Class("Bob", 0)
class2 = Class("John", 1)
print(Class.search_by_id(0).name) # prints Bob
print(Class.search_by_id(1).name) # prints John
print(Class.search_by_id(2).name) # prints raised a KeyError since id 2 doesn't exist yet: KeyError: 'No user with id 2'
```

Comment: Thas a perfect answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want that each time you instance a person they have a new id, you can do this:

```
class MyClass():
    ids = 0
    id_list = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = "name"
        MyClass.ids += 1
        self.myId = MyClass.ids
        MyClass.id_list[self.myId] = self

   def search_by_id(id):
      return MyClass.id_list[id]

bob = MyClass("bob")
kyle = MyClass("kyle")
print(bob.myId)
print(kyle.myId)
print(MyClass.search_by_id(2).name)

>1
>2
>kyle
```